# jQuery detect keyboard press then focus to textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery function that detect if some key in keyboard pressed. So far that worked, example if I press "P" then it will focus to textbox.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e)
{
if (e.keyCode == 51 || e.keyCode == 52 || e.keyCode == 80 || e.keyCode == 65)
{
    $("#code_read_box").focus();
}
});
```

Now I want when I press "P", "P" will set too to textbox.

```
<input type="text" id="code_read_box" value=""/>
```

Any advice ?

[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/d4EvC/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);

    if (key.match(/[34PA]/) && !$('input').is(':focus')) {
        $('input').focus();
        $('input').val($('input').val() + key);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean. Give me a moment to fix

Comment: I tried but now still problem when I want to type AP, it will be PA

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.fromCharCode`:

```
String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hw2g5/

Your code:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 51 || e.keyCode == 52 || e.keyCode == 80 || e.keyCode == 65) {
    $("#code_read_box").focus();
    $("#code_read_box").val(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
  }
});
```

If you want to append values, so:

```
$("#code_read_box").val($("#code_read_box").val() + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
```

Comment: OK tried, worked. But why when I press A two times, it will back to just 1 A ?

Comment: Edit after your comment

Comment: and now when type A, it will set double... :(

Comment: Leave the focus from textbox or change your logic- we don't know what do you want to get- just answer the questions.